# How to cast `forall a. a -> a` back to `a -> a`?

Tags: haskell, types, type-inference

In my actual problem I have a function `f`, passed as a parameter, that changes the order in a list but has no requirements regarding type and does not change the type either. I want to apply that function on `[Int]` and `[Bool]` so I have to resolve both contexts trying to typecast `f` to either `[Int] -> [Int]` or `[Bool] -> [Bool]`. I solved this with `Rank2Types`.
But then I use `any` on a list of functions like `f` and `any` requires the functions to be `[a] -> [a]` rather than `forall a. [a] -> [a]`.

The code below while nonsensical perfectly reproduces the error:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}

--debug :: (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Bool 
debug swap = any combine [swap]
  where
    combine :: (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Bool
    combine f =  usefonBool f && usefonInt f
    --usefonBool :: (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Bool
    usefonBool f = f [True,True] == [False]

    --usefonInt :: (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Bool
    usefonInt f = (f [1,2]) == [2,1]
```

The error message is:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘forall a1. [a1] -> [a1]’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the inferred type of debug :: a -> Bool
    at /path/debug.hs:(4,1)-(12,36)
  Expected type: a -> Bool
    Actual type: (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Bool
• In the first argument of ‘any’, namely ‘combine’
  In the expression: any combine [swap]
  In an equation for ‘debug’:
      debug swap
        = any combine [swap]
        where
            combine :: (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Bool
            combine f = usefonBool f && usefonInt f
            usefonBool f = f [True, ....] == [False]
            usefonInt f = (f [1, ....]) == [2, ....]
• Relevant bindings include
    swap :: a (bound at /path/debug.hs:4:7)
    debug :: a -> Bool (bound at /path/debug.hs:4:1)
|
```

My goal is to find an annotation that lets me use an `f` on different types and then apply any on a list of such generic functions.

If I uncomment all my type annotations (or just the top one) the error changes to

```
• Couldn't match type ‘[a0] -> [a0]’ with ‘forall a. [a] -> [a]’
  Expected type: ([a0] -> [a0]) -> Bool
    Actual type: (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Bool
• In the first argument of ‘any’, namely ‘combine’
  In the expression: any combine [swap]
  In an equation for ‘debug’:
      debug swap
        = any combine [swap]
        where
            combine :: (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Bool
            combine f = usefonBool f && usefonInt f
            usefonBool :: (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Bool
            usefonBool f = f [True, ....] == [False]
            ....
  |
```

Comment: And why did you comment out the type signatures?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I commented them out to present a version that made as few assumptions as possilble.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. GHC can only infer Rank-1 types, so you _must_ use explicit signatures. In this case, the top-level one should be enough. – But anyway, it's generally a bad idea to omit signatures.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Uncommenting *my* top-level signature doesn't solve it yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that `Rank2Types` is a deprecated name.  It's equivalent to `RankNTypes` in modern GHC, and that's the preferred name for the extension.

Here's the underlying problem.  A "list of such generic functions" could have the type:

```
[forall a. [a] -> [a]]
```

Sadly, this isn't a valid Haskell type because Haskell doesn't support "impredicative polymorphism".  Specifically, the following program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
myFunctions :: [forall a. [a] -> [a]]
myFunctions = [f1, f2]
   where f1 (x:y:rest) = y:x:rest
         f2 = reverse
```

produces the error message:

> ```
> DebugRank.hs:2:16: error:
>     • Illegal polymorphic type: forall a. [a] -> [a]
>       GHC doesn't yet support impredicative polymorphism
>     • In the type signature: myFunctions :: [forall a. [a] -> [a]]
> ```

There's an extension, `ImpredicativeTypes`.  It's flakey and incomplete, but it allows the following to compile:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ImpredicativeTypes #-}

myFunctions :: [forall a. [a] -> [a]]
myFunctions = [f1, f2]
   where f1 (x:y:rest) = y:x:rest
         f2 = reverse

debug :: [forall a. [a] -> [a]] -> Bool
debug = any combine
  where
    combine :: (forall a. [a] -> [a]) -> Bool
    combine f = usefonBool f && usefonInt f
    usefonBool f = f [True,True] == [False]
    usefonInt  f = f [1,2] == [2,1]

main = print (debug myFunctions)
```

I'd still recommend against using it, though.

The usual alternative is to use a `newtype` wrapper for the polymorphic function:

```
newtype ListFunction = ListFunction (forall a. [a] -> [a])
```

This requires some boilerplate, but no extensions other than `RankNTypes`:

```
myFunctions :: [ListFunction]
myFunctions = [ListFunction f1, ListFunction f2]
   where f1 (x:y:rest) = y:x:rest
         f2 = reverse

debug :: [ListFunction] -> Bool
debug = any combine
  where
    combine :: ListFunction -> Bool
    combine (ListFunction f) = usefonBool f && usefonInt f
    usefonBool f = f [True,True] == [False]
    usefonInt  f = f [1,2] == [2,1]
```

The complete code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype ListFunction = ListFunction (forall a. [a] -> [a])

myFunctions :: [ListFunction]
myFunctions = [ListFunction f1, ListFunction f2]
   where f1 (x:y:rest) = y:x:rest
         f2 = reverse

debug :: [ListFunction] -> Bool
debug = any combine
  where
    combine :: ListFunction -> Bool
    combine (ListFunction f) = usefonBool f && usefonInt f
    usefonBool f = f [True,True] == [False]
    usefonInt  f = f [1,2] == [2,1]

main = print $ debug myFunctions
```

Comment: I don't really get why `Rank2Types` is _deprecated_. Lots of applications (this one included) really only require rank-2, nothing higher, and there's actually a valid reason why you might want to restrict it to that: rank-2 polymorphisms still allows type inference, which rank-N doesn't. Of course, GHC doesn't implement this, but it could conceivably do. Meanwhile, specifying `Rank2` works just as well. OTOH, `ImpredicativeTypes` _should_ be deprecated – it doesnt work properly, has never worked properly and probably won't any time soon.